# Creating XAConnection instance from ActiveMQXASslConnectionFactory instance fails

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I enabled transport over SSL connection in server side and I want to create SSL connection to the server. Creating XAConnection instance from ActiveMQXASslConnectionFactory instance fails. Here is my code:

```
ActiveMQXASslConnectionFactory sslConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQXASslConnectionFactory(mqUrl);
try {
    sslConnectionFactory.setKeyStore("file:" + keystoreFile);
    sslConnectionFactory.setKeyStorePassword(keystorePassword);
    sslConnectionFactory.setTrustStore("file:" + truststoreFile);
    sslConnectionFactory.setTrustStorePassword(truststorePassword);
} catch (Exception ex) {
}

XAConnection connection = sslConnectionFactory.createXAConnection();
```

When I run the example code it throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: xaAckMode
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXASslConnectionFactory.configureXAConnection(ActiveMQXASslConnectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXASslConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQXASslConnectionFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:266)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:238)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXASslConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(ActiveMQXASslConnectionFactory.java:48)
```

Is this a bug? Please help.

Comment: A `NoSuchFieldError` suggests that you are using incompatible versions of dependencies (libraries).

Comment: I had a mistake in pom.xml. I removed activemq-core dependency and problem solved.

Comment: If you've solved the problem you should "answer" your own question here and mark it as such so it's clear for others who might run into this issue in the future. Or you can just delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. There is a different version of dependency in pom.xml. I removed it and the code executed successfully.